# The Things Network - Pricing

Tags: lora, lorawan

I am planning to use [The Things Network](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/) for my next project with around 50 LoRa nodes geographically distributed in an area. I am wondering is LoRaWAN free to use - provided we buy LoRaWAN gateway from TTN.

Comment: I believe the answer is *yes*, if you are on an unlicensed frequency, it's free of charge once you have the hardware.  It's just quora, but check out [this page](https://www.quora.com/Is-LoRaWAN-totally-free-of-charge); they indicate that lora makes their money on sales of hardware, not use of the frequencies.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's free.

The idea is similar to the original Internet model, if you set up a gateway you allow others to use it as well and in return you can use other peoples gateways, that way the overall coverage grows and everybody benefits.

You don't need to buy a gateway from TTN, you can use any number of gateways<sup>*</sup>, but I think TTN are now asking that you use proper multi channel receivers that support multiple spreading settings and not just basic 2 channel rigs as they don't really add much utility.

<sup>*</sup>  I am currently waiting on [this](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/pisupply/iot-lora-boards-your-gateway-to-the-internet-of-th) kickstarter to deliver my gateway and a pi hat client board to set up a gateway in my home town.

Comment: Follow on (harder) question, will it always be free?

Comment: That is unanswerable, but given the backbone is built on other people's internet connection it would he hard to move it away from this model (but not impossible).